# Minor criteria for Positive or negative definiteness

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, hessian-matrix

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -4 & 0\\ 
-4 &  8 & 0\\ 
 0&  0&-3 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Clearly $$\Delta _1=2 >0$$

$$\Delta _2=0 $$

$$\Delta _3=0 $$

Now how can I decide whether $A$ is positive definite or negative definite ? or semi positive definite or semi negative definite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to look at all principal minors, not just the *leading* principal minors. For example discarding the first column and the first row you get a negative principal minor of -24. The matrix is indefinite. Alternatively you could calculate the Eigenvalues, see that there is a positive and a negative Eigenvalue and come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion):

"a Hermitian matrix $M'$is positive-semidefinite if and only if all principal minors of $M$ are nonnegative"

Of course in the case where all minors are - stricly - postive your matrix will be positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

If at least one diagonal element is positive and at least one diagonal element is negative, the matrix is indefinite.